# Why the different punctuation in Debian package file names vs source directory?

Tags: debian, package-management, source

In a Debian archive file, the package name and the version string is typically separated by an underscore, for instance `foo-bar_1.2.3.tar.gz`. The top directory in the archive, on the other hand, has a hyphen instead of an underscore, for instance `foo-bar-1.2.3`. What is the reason for this and where is this convention described?

Comment: @roaima this question is about the use of underscore as a separator in package filenames v. hyphen inside the tarball, not about the difference between hyphen and underscore as separators in package filenames.

Comment: @roaima What exactly is unclear?

Comment: @Kusalananda Not a dupe. The question clearly (to me) compares underscores in `the package name and the version string` to hyphens in `the top directory in the archive`. StephenKitt's comment mentions this too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very helpful for the names of the `.tar.gz` and other files that make up the Debian source package to be uniform, since they end up installed on mirror sites in a fixed structure.  Here, an underscore is used in order to remove ambiguity: hyphens are permitted in both the package name and the version, so if a hyphen were also used as the separator then it wouldn't be clear which was which.  The naming is described (non-normatively) in an [appendix to the Debian Policy Manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/#source-packages-as-archives), although some of the details of which files form part of source packages are out of date in that appendix and [dpkg-source(1)](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/dpkg-dev/dpkg-source.1.en.html) is a better reference there.

I don't recall ever seeing a clear reason for why `dpkg-source` unpacks source packages to `<package>-<upstream_version>` rather than to `<package>_<upstream_version>`, although my best guess is that it was simply because that was the usual convention for how tarballs distributed by upstream maintainers would unpack at the time `dpkg-source` was written (and to a large extent still is), so it made things look least surprising.